# how do you output the results of a collections.defaultdict(list) from a nested list into jinja?

Tags: python, jinja2

**My python code**

```
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for k in results:
  d[k[0]].append(k[1:4])

e= collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))

for key,value in e.items():
    for p in xrange(len(value)):
        print value[p][0]
```

**What I want to do**

How can I select values in jinja from this bit?

```
for key,value in e.items():
    for p in xrange(len(value)):
        print value[p][0]
```

I thought it would be:

```
  {%for key, value in groups.items()%}
    {%for p in xrange(len(value))%}
  <tr>
    <td>{{value[p][1]}}</td><td>{{value[p][2]}}</td><td>{{value[p][4]}}</td>
    <td>{{value[p][5]}}</td><td>{{value[p][3]}}</td>
  </tr>
   {%endfor%}
  {%endfor%}
```

Although this produces an error

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'len' is undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use an `xrange()`; you can loop over the value list directly:

```
{%for key, value in groups.items()%}
  {%for elem in value %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ elem[1] }}</td><td>{{ elem[2] }}</td><td>{{ elem[4] }}</td>
      <td>{{ elem[5] }}</td><td>{{ elem[3] }}</td>
    </tr>
  {%endfor%}
{%endfor%}
```

If you do need the length of an object (like a list), in a Jinja template, use the [`length` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#length):

```
{% if value|length < 5 %}Short list!{% endif %}
```

`count` is an alias for `length`.

There is no `xrange()` callable in Jinja, but you do get [`range()`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#range).

Answer (score 0):

as @Martijn Pieters said you can iterate on the `list` elements but in order to answer why you get that exception:

`len` is undefined but you can use `length()` insted:

length as written in the docs will return the number of items of a sequence or mapping. You can read more [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#length)

Also to get the leagnth you can use `count()` like `list_size = my_list.count()`